# How can I refactor getAll() method for the service business logic?

Tags: java

I'm working with the following [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/service/impl/ProjectServiceImpl.java#L28), where I have *business-logic* as:

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectAdaptor projectAdaptor;

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects(Long companyId) {
        return projectRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(project -> Objects.equals(project.getId(), companyId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Project save(Project project) {
        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProjectDTO> findAllProducts() {
        List<Project> project = projectRepository.findAll();
        return projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDtoList(project);
    }
}
```

in the provided class above I have the `getAllProjects()` method that returns me all projects based on parameter as `companyId`.

```
@Override
public List<Project> getAllProjects(Long companyId) {
    return projectRepository.findAll().stream()
            .filter(project -> Objects.equals(project.getId(), companyId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want to understand, how I can improve this logic in more proper way. For example, how can I get directly from database all projects without filtering it in the code?

Also do I need to use the additional parameter in the method declaration or do I need to rewrite it fully?

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @Toby Speight, got it, I'll try to improve my question a bit later. Thank you for helpful links related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't suggest any real alternatives, since you don't give enough information, but I do have a review in form of some questions, some of which also apply to that method:

- Why does the filtering happen in this service instead of the repository i.e. the database?
- Why is the parameter called `companyId` when it is being compared to the project ID?
- Are there actually different projects with the same ID?
- Why is the method called `getAllProjects` when it actually doesn't return all projects especially since there is a confusingly similar named method `findAllProjects`?
- Why does `findAllProjects` return a list of `ProjectDTO`s while all other methods directly use the `Project` entity?

And one final concrete suggestion: Spring has basically deprecated property injection (it's no longer in the official documentation). Constructor injection is the preferred method.

Comment: Thank you for useful questions. I need to handle them in the project.